# Responsive Layout with DIV Percentages

Tags: html, css, nested, responsive

I've have started working on a new PHP based chat system for one of my projects and recently I've been spending a lot of time reading about Responsive layouts, I've decided that I'd like to avoid using bootstrap even so it does offer lots of great features, and I feel there is more to learn in doing things from scratch then using an already established set of code...that being said.

Here is some sample code I put together that is not behaving the way I expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Chat Room </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0l; maximum-scale=1.0;  user-scalable=0;" >

<style type="text/css">
#container 
  {
    position:relative;
    width:90%;
    height:600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }

#messages
  {
    width:75%;
    margin:5px;
    padding:10px;
    height:80%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
  }

#users
  {
    width:21%;
    margin:5px;
    padding:10px;
    height:80%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    float: left;
  }  

#message_entry
  {
    width:100%;
    margin:5px;
    padding:10px;
    height:20%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    clear: left;
  }    
</style>
</head>
  <body width="device-width">

<div id="container">
    <div id="messages">
        Existing Messages
    </div>

    <div id="users">
        User List
    </div>   

    <div id="message_entry">
        New Message Box
    </div>        
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I noticed that the percentages assigned to inner DIV's don't seem to relate to their parent div as in the case of "message_entry" to the container.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is it not doing as expected?  You haven't really asked a question yet.

Comment: While it's commendable to want to learn for yourself, I would say it's absolutely worth referring to Bootstrap's docs to understand their approach, since they are now arguably the benchmark for solid responsive layout. For example, setting `<body width="device-width">` will only ever cause problems, since you are already correctly setting `device-width` in a meta tag.

Comment: take out '<body width="device-width">' you have the meta tag '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0l; maximum-scale=1.0;  user-scalable=0;" >'

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container 
  {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
 float:left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }

#messages
  {
    width:71% ;
    margin:2%; /*  <=== ^^^ 1 horizontal margin (left) of 2% */
    padding:3%;
    height:75%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* all the width (padding + borders) and height (padding + borders) whitout the margins */
  }

#users
  {
    width:21% ;
    margin:2%;/*  <=== ^^^ 1 horizontal margin of (right)2% */
    padding:3%;
    height:75%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }  

#message_entry
  {
    width:96%; /* 100% - ( 2% * 2) <=== ^^^ 2 horizontal  margins of 2% */
    margin:2%; /* ■ ■ ■ */
    padding:3%; 
    height:19%; /* 25% - (2% * 3  ) <=== ^^^ 2 vertical + 1 ■ ■ ■ vertical margin */
    border: 1px solid green;
    float:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

```html
<body >

<div id="container">
    <div id="messages">
        Existing Messages
    </div>

    <div id="users">
        User List
    </div>   

    <div id="message_entry">
        New Message Box
    </div>        
</div>
</body>
```

You need to work all in percentages and contemplate the margins in the total width.

For example: in 'messages' the total width is going to be 75% because we have 71% of width plus two margins (Left and right) of 2%, … in 'users' the total width is going to be 25%  because we have width: 21%  plus 2  margins of 2% (left and right)…Grand total = 100 %.

In relation with ‘message_entry’: We need that takes the same width than 'users' + 'messages'.

'users' has two horizontal margins (left and Right), and the same 'messages';  but the only ones that affect us are the 'users' left one and the 'messages' right one; 'users’ right and  'message' left don’t , because 'message_entry' has them too.  That is the reason why 'message' has a width of 96%.

The same logic is for height parameter.

Note: Use    ‘box-sizing: border-box’ and you only will be worried about de margins.

Comment: Thank you Omar, the suggestion regarding the width calculation was a great piece of info, that was and it has helped greatly...I'm going to investigate the "box-sizing: border-box;" property as well, when I have the layout that I am looking for I'll post back my desired result...thanks again for the info.

Comment: You also don't need `width: 100%` on the `#container` element since the div already takes up 100% of the width of its parent.